# Capistrano 3 alternative to exists? capistrano 2 method

Tags: exists, capistrano3

In Capistrano 2 it was pretty easy to check if variable was set with

```
exists?(:variable)
```

In capistrano 3 exists? method was removed as I get 'undefined method exists?' as i try to run the task.

So what is the alternative way to check if variable was set in capistrano 3?

Comment: have you tried using `defined?(:variable)` ?

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. It's not capistrano-defined method, I guess, so it can't read variables defined by capistrano 'set' method. It always returns true for both defined and undefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the fetch method to access configuration variables.

Checking if a variable is set can be done like this:

```
set :variable, ask('Variable: ', nil) unless fetch(:variable)
```